# Select objects that share a ManyToMany Relationship (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model called `House` and another one called `Location` which have a ManyToMany relationship between eachother. Example, a house can be in both location `Brooklyn` and in `New York`.

From my `New York` page, I want to display "Relevant Locations" or "Nearby Location". I want to select all locations that share the same houses as `New York` do.

So for example.

House A: `Brooklyn`, `New York`

House B: `Manhattan`, `New York`

From `New York` I want to select locations `Brooklyn`, `Manhattan`.

I would also like to order them by the amount of houses they share. To get the most "relevant" location first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some (untested) code that should give you a clue on how you can achieve this:

```
# my_location is a Location object representing New York
similar_locations = {}

for house in House.ojects.filter(locations=my_location):  # get all houses in New York
    for house_location in house.locations.all():  # get all locations of all houses in New York
        # count the houses in each location
        if not house_location.pk in similar_locations:
            similar_locations[house_location.pk] = 1 
        else:
            similar_locations[house_locoation.pk] += 1

# sort the dictionary of locations by number of houses
# sorted_similar_locations will be a list of tuples sorted by the second element in each tuple.
import operator
sorted_similar_locations = reversed(sorted(similar_locations.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

# get Django objects of your locations (this depends on how many similar locations you expect. If it is a lot, this query is very inefficient)
locations = Location.objects.filter(pk__in=similar_locations.keys())
```

There are probably more efficient ways on doing this. But it should give you a good start! Hope this helps.